# Can I please get some feedback on this `isPalindrome()` function in C?

Tags: c, palindrome

I'm writing some useful functions in C. One of them is `isPalindrome()`.

I figured to determine if a number is a palindrome or not, I should...

- get all digits in an array
- iterate through with two indexes - start one at 0 and one to the array count
- increment/decrement the indexes whilst subscripting the array whilst they match and if the array count gets to 0 we have a palindrome (i.e. finishing going through all digits).

I came up with...

```
int isPalindrome(int num) {

    int places[100];
    int i = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        places[i++] = num % 10; 
        num /= 10;
    }

    int j = 0;
    while (i >= 0 && places[j++] == places[--i]) {
    }
    return i == -1;

}
```

Is this generally how it is done?

I'm learning C by myself, and although I can tell when my code compiles and doesn't take all day to work something out, I don't have any *expert eyes* to tell me if I'm on the right track.

So, any improvements or suggestions on my code?

Thanks very much!

Comment: IsPalindrome is a useful function? For whom? ;-)

Comment: @Steven: It could be useful for people doing [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net) challenges. :)

Comment: Project Euler *is* why I wrote this :)

Comment: For `places`, probably `100` elements are not required, because the input is `int`, and `INT_MAX = +2,147,483,647` has only `10` digits,

Comment: @Greg we have vastly different definitions of "useful" ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to loop while `i > j`. Once `i <= j`, you are just checking all the characters a second time.

Comment: @pmg: when i == j the comparison will always be true.

Comment: @Jeremy: yes, but it's the first time *that* comparison is done.

Answer (score 2):

Although using inline `++` and `--` operators in the following might seem clever:

```
while (i >= 0 && places[j++] == places[--i]) { 
}
```

your code will be easier to read if you put those *inside* the loop body:

```
while (i >= 0 && places[j] == places[i-1]) { 
    j++;
    i--;
}
```

This way, the reader of the code won't have to think about the possible side effects of changing the values of `i` and `j` within the conditional test. There will probably be no measurable effect on the speed of the compiled code (although, if performance is important to this function, you should check with your compiler).

Also, you've got a bug where you will access `places[-1]` if `i == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use `sprintf` to "convert the string to digits":

```
char places[100];
sprintf(places, "%i", num);
i = strlen(places);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful. Unfortunately I didn't know about this when I wrote the code.

Answer (score 1):

In java

```
static boolean isPalindrome(String p) {
    return p.equals(new StringBuilder(p).reverse().toString());
}
```

In c++ and c

```
int IsPalindrome(char *string) {
    int bottom = 0, top;

    top = strlen(string) - 1;
    while(bottom < top && string[bottom] == string[top]) {
        ++bottom;
        --top;
    }
    return (bottom >= top ? 1:0);
}
```

Note, You need to write **itoa** function, if you need to do this for a number input. Or use ( [link](http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1587/Integer-String-1.htm) ).

Thats how it is generally done. This would also work for all bases and not only 10.

Comment: while we're on the topic of other languages ... in scala -> def isPalindrome(p: String) = p.equals(p.reverse)

Comment: My possible palindrome is not a string, it is an 'int'.

Comment: If you mean shorter is better then in J it is: `((-:|.)@:":)"0`

Comment: @alex Yes, I considered that as bug.

Comment: In C++ I'd use std::string rather than char* and then either use the begin/rbegin to get a forward and reverse iterator, or make a reverse_copy of the string and then compare as you did for the Java solution.